# SQL: Get dates with two specific events

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Table: 
    Logs
Fields:    
    LogDate datetime,
    ErrId int
```

ErrId 9 and 5 sometimes occur on same date. 
How can I find those dates?
Of course the task can be about any pair of ErrIds not just 9 and 5.

I ended up with following sql statement:

```
select  distinct l_1.LogDate
from logs l_1
where exists (select * from logs l_2 where l_1.LogDate = l_2.LogDate and l_2.ErrId = 9)
  and exists (select * from logs l_3 where l_1.LogDate = l_3.LogDate and l_3.ErrId = 5)
```

The question: is there better solution for the task?

Comment: What type of DB is it?

Comment: @kometen: SQL Server

Comment: Thank you. I have added the sql-server tag and is waiting for a peer review. Pls. tag any future questions with the type of DB as well as the more generic sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a self-join like this:

```
select     distinct l_1.LogDate
from       logs l_1
inner join logs l_2 on l_1.LogDate = l_2.LogDate
where      l_1.ErrId = 9
and        l_2.ErrId = 5
```

Note that generally it is better to use `group by` instead of `distinct`. Give it a try:

```
select     l_1.LogDate
from       logs l_1
inner join logs l_2 on l_1.LogDate = l_2.LogDate
where      l_1.ErrId = 9
and        l_2.ErrId = 5
group by   l_1.LogDate
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! So simple :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest method is simply `group by` with `having`:

```
select l.LogDate
from logs l
group by l.log_date
having sum(case when l.ErrId = 9 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when l.ErrId = 5 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

If you are only looking for a fixed set of values, you can also write this as:

```
select l.LogDate
from logs l
where l.ErrId in (5, 9)
group by l.log_date
having count(distinct l.ErrId) = 2;
```

Both of these should be faster than doing a `group by`/`distinct` along with a join.

Comment: Great! Thank you, Gordon!